# Trying to add fadeIn/Out to div with single button(div)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue. I have a code for hidden and visible div, which all works, but I'd like to add fadeIn and Out to it, but it just either doesn't work or it hides my control div.
Here is my code:
Edit: Yap I'm demented, I could just use **toggle**, don't know why I didn't, guess it was really late

````
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.text_container').addClass("hidden");

        $('.text_container').click(function() {
            var $this = $(this);

            if ($this.hasClass("hidden")) {
                $(this).removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
                
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
            }
        });
    }); ```
````

Comment: You can just use `fadeToggle()` for this - however if the `.text_container` is hidden when the page loads how can you click it again?

Comment: Hi! Could you provide also your CSS class **hidden** and **visible**! Just edit your post.

Comment: Also note that you only need "default" and "not-default" eg just ".hidden" - if you remove hidden then it would resort to the default of not-hidden.   ie if you set your css correctly you only need to add/remove one class, not two.